# Java AWT Window implementation not running paint() function

Tags: java, graphics, awt

(I am fully aware this is an old way to go about this - I have to do it this way)

I am trying to use the `Window` class of `AWT` to draw basic visuals to the screen - the window shows up, but, despite the fact that the `paint()` function is being run(Tested with `sysout`) - nothing shows up.

The problematic code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class a {

    static a a = new a();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        b b = a.new b();
        b.setVisible(true);
        b.pack();
    }
    class b extends Frame {
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 16, 16);
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone knows what is causing this or how to rectify it I would greatly appreciate your assistance.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed an extra Canvas object to draw onto - here's the functioning code for anyone having the problem I had

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class a {

    static a a = new a();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Frame f = new Frame();
        b b = a.new b();
        f.add(b);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.pack();
    }
    class b extends Canvas {
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 16, 16);
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```